# Javascript to add class to last of class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following input and list:

```
<input id="myinput" type="text">

<ul id="mylist">
    <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="display"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="display"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

with the following css to show/hide certain list items:

```
.display {
    display: block;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.last {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I'm looking for javascript (preferably vanilla) to add `last` class to the LAST item with `display` class, so that I can highlight that item with CSS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6vr3czd/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on `Element.querySelectorAll` to scan the element top to bottom up and down (DFS might be a better term). This makes the last node to be the last as you would define it.
I found official [documentation](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-shadow-including-tree-order) about it.

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".display");
var last = nodes[nodes.length - 1];
last.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="myinput" type="text">

  <ul id="mylist">
    <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="display"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="display"><a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <ul id="mylist2">
        <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="display"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li class="display"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="hide"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```